# Which MATLAB optimization for constraining possible solutions to specific coordinates?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm new to optimization with matlab and am unsure what optimisation to use and how to add any constraint...

I have an object in a 100x100 design space

[image: Object]

I have the boundary of the object in X and Y coordinates (`bound` = 2x200 vector).

I want to find a subset of the coordinates (e.g. 2x10 vector) that minimises a function. 
The misfit function is smooth and non-linear.

Which optimisation do you suggest to use (in the papers I've read with similar problems `ga` seems to be popular)
How do I constrain an optimisation so that only the values in `bound` are allowed?

Comment: If the constraint cannot be defined mathematically then it looks like a `location allocation` problem which, often, cannot be solved directly (due to the large number of possible combination) a typical example is the traveling salesman problem. The algorithms used to solved this kind of problem usually output a good solution but not necessarily the best solution.

Comment: In your case if you want to choose 10 pairs of coordinate among 200, you have ~2.25*10^16 possible combination. You should also describe your problem.